# HERE Maps CSP error on Safari browser: blobs can't be loaded

Tags: javascript, here-api, content-security-policy

I am working on a webpage which integrates the JAVASCRIPT HERE MAPS SDK which works fine so far. For security reasons, we now introduced CSP to the website. Ever since that, HERE maps don't work properly on Safari browser anymore. The map canvas as such is loaded but remains gray with no map details nor working controls. According to the browser console/inspector, several blobs can't be loaded due to CSP violations.

I have not been fiddling around for hours to get the right CSP settings inside my HTML META tag but I just won't get it working on Safari browser. For debugging reasons, I even tried a very unsafe solutions which pretty much "allows everything" just to get it working, but even with this code, the blobs remain blocked:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
    content="default-src * data: gap: content: mediastream: blob: filesystem: about: ws: wss: 'unsafe-eval' 'wasm-unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline';
      child-src 'self' data: mediastream: blob: filesystem: about: ws: wss: 'unsafe-eval' 'wasm-unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline';
      worker-src 'self' data: gap: content: mediastream: blob: filesystem: about: ws: wss: 'unsafe-eval' 'wasm-unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; 
script-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; 
connect-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; 
object-src * data: blob: filesystem: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' ;
img-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; 
frame-src * data: blob: ; 
style-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline';
font-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline';
frame-ancestors * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline';">
```

Anyone else experiencing this or might have a clue, what I might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Providing an error message would be very useful. But the most likely cause is that there is some default CSP set on your site. Introducing another policy in a meta tag doesn't change anything as content needs to pass all policies present. You should identify how the original policy is set and modify that one instead.

Comment: There are basically two types of error: 

[Error] Refused to load
blob:https://fooo because it does not appear in the worker-src directive of the Content Security Policy.

and 

[Error] Tangram [error]: Scene.load() failed to load
blob:https://fooo: The operation is insecure.

What do you mean by the "original policy"? Apart from mine, there is no other policy on the client side. Are you referring to the server side?

Comment: It is just too common that people ask questions here scratching their heads about not getting their policy to work, and the reason is always that there is a default policy that blocks the content. Blob seems to be allowed in your worker-src, so I can't really see what is wrong with that policy.

Comment: Ok but where does this default policy reside? How do I change that? Does that reside on the server side where PHP handles the HTTP headers?

Comment: Check your response header and meta tags if there are any, if there are you'll have some text to search for.